# Update Amazon EC2 Rightscale Centos for latest GLIBC

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2

We've run into an issue on an Amazon EC2 instance where we need a later version of glibc.

I understand I need to update Centos (current version is 5.6) to acheive this, and I've tried various approaches to doing this including the one mentioned here
http://www.webhostbug.com/upgrade-centos-6-5-7/

and here

[upgrade CentOS from 6.5 to 7 in an EC2 Instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/628533/upgrade-centos-from-6-5-to-7-in-an-ec2-instance)

I can get the pre-upgrade assistant to install (I think) but not run

There is also an issue that this is running Rightscale, and I think it's a 32bit host.

I managed to upgrade from 5.4 to 5.6 by editing CentOS-Base.repo and changing all the 5.4s to 5.6 which let me update some with yum update. However I can't seem to upgrade any further with this approach.

I just need to get to a version with glibc version 2.7

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use the upgrade assistant to upgrade from CentOS 6 to CentOS 7, you can't use it to upgrade from CentOS 5 to CentOS 7. You will need to start new CentOS 7 instances. (And unless you have some good reason to use the Rightscale images, you should use the official CentOS AMIs. I've found a LOT of inexcusably broken stuff in Rightscale AMIs.)

Comment: Hmm OK. At the risk of taking on more than I can chew.. is it possible to upgrade from 5 to 6 with such a tool or similar?

Comment: No, there's no supported upgrade path from 5.